# How to use npm in ASP.NET Core

Tags: npm, asp.net-core, package

I am writing a server `api` using `ASP.NET Core` which will be used by android app,
The task is to provide all the persons in the radius of `5 km` 
I want to use npm  package `google-distance`,But how can i use that in my cs File
as i am writing only an api no frontend,

The code i want to use is

```
var distance = require('google-distance');

distance.get(
  {
    origin: 'San Francisco, CA',
    destination: 'San Diego, CA'
  },
  function(err, data) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(data);
});
```

as per documentation of google-distance npm
I know the above is node Code

How can i use this in my ASP.NET Core API

Comment: Try to explore NodeServices in ASP.NET Core, it might help.

Comment: Hmm seems intersting

Comment: You can call the underlying API for this yourself - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/

Comment: No with the node services i got an entry to all node packages and powerfull javscript